# Call SQL Procedure with CreateNativeQuery

Tags: mysql, hibernate, procedure

My SQL procedure contains two Queries and I want call that procedure from my java code
I  tired with below code but it return result List with first query from procedure.

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("{call voucherRedemption(?,?,?)}");
    query.setParameter(1, loggedinWorkSpaceId);
    query.setParameter(2, startDate);
    query.setParameter(3, endDate);
    List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();
```

Procedure are as below:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE `cer`.`voucherRedemption`(IN workspaceId int(10), IN  startDate VARCHAR(30),
    IN endDate VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
select w.ws_name as wsName,str_to_date(startDate, '%Y-%m-%d') as startDate,str_to_date(endDate, '%Y-%m-%d') as endDate 
from  workspace w where w.ws_id = workspaceId;

select money.*,money.paidAmount + money.prepaidAmount - money.clientCost,programs.programs
from program;   END
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `EntityManager#createStoredProcedureQuery` like this:

```java
StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("voucherRedemption");
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(3, String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
query.setParameter(1, loggedinWorkSpaceId);
query.setParameter(2, startDate);
query.setParameter(3, endDate);
List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();
```

I haven't used this to actually get a result, only to executre a procedure. Let me know if this works.